# Maven Mulesoft Anypointstudio Scheduler

Tags: api, maven, scheduler, mule4

I would like install Mule Scheduler Service Implementation in Anypoint Studio.(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mule.services/mule-service-scheduler/1.1.4)
I add this dependency to my pom.xml in my project.

My project was deployed with this dependency. Someone know how use this dependency and know how it working ? I was thinking to use it to for API's. Maybe someone have some example?
I would like use it to get the list of my all scheduler in API's that I use.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mule-scheduler-service is the backend implementation of the scheduler functionality inside a Mule 4 deployment. Imagine it is a plugin or extension for Mule. You are not supposed to try to use it in a Mule application, or really in any kind of application other than Mule 4. Sure, you can add the dependency to a pom, but it will not do you any good.